# React final form submit form not working after validate props got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

When I use validate props in the Form component after got error, submitForm isn't working anymore.
Sandbox Link
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-bose-dp69z

Answer (score 0):

Passing in submit errors as a prop and reading them in the client-side validation function is very awkward. You can just [*return the errors* from `onSubmit`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#submission-errors), and they will show up as `meta.submitError` for each field.